# :after class doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I need to place the `div` *content* before the element, so I have used `:before` class. But it doesn't work. What could be the reason for it? Is there something incorrect with `css`?

```css
.led {
 /* Yellow LED */
 margin-top: 3px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 7px 0px, inset #808002 0 0px 9px, #D4D400 0 2px 12px;
    margin-left: 80%;
}

.led:before {
 content: "Connecting";
 padding-left: 18px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='led'> </div>
```

Comment: change .led:before to .led::before

Comment: @Jugnu No, doesn't work.

Comment: add  display:inline-block in .led class http://jsfiddle.net/SUKYw/

Comment: @Jugnu Doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide fiddle/plnkr?

Comment: Can you post the image which is shown your desire structure?

Comment: working on myside ...which version of chrome your using??

Comment: @Jugnu Does it? http://jsfiddle.net/k3y3oLnu/

Comment: @Jugnu Also edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine with CSS. As I understand `:before` and `:after`, it will add a content inside your div element. So, it will look something like this:

```
<div class="led">
    <!-- content added with :before, Connecting in your case -->
    Your div content
    <!-- content added with :after -->
</div>
```

Problem that you are facing is that there is no content inside `.led` div, so `:before` and `:after` seem to have the same result. Your css defines `.led` div to have width of only 14px, so there is no place for *Connecting* text. You can try something like this for a quick (and ugly) fix:

```css
.led:before {
    content: 'Connecting';
    margin-left: -60px; /* CHANGED */
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
.led {
    /* Yellow LED */
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 7px 0px, inset #808002 0 0px 9px, #D4D400 0 2px 12px;
    margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="led"></div>
```

Better solution might be to enclose `.led` div with another one and add `:before` to that parent div, something like this:

```css
.holder {
    margin-left: 80%;
}
.holder:before {
    content: 'Connecting';
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
.led {
    /* Yellow LED */
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #FF0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 3px 7px 0px, inset #808002 0 0px 9px, #D4D400 0 2px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder"><div class="led"></div></div>
```